# Fiware suitable Components

Tags: iot, fiware, node-red

Could someone suggest me suitable components to build a full path using fiware components?In the path i would like to register mobile devices  to a broker (also Node-RED for getting info from broker).Above the broker i want to have a Complex Event Processing engine for  the complex events.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read the following article about asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Devices can be registered to Orion Context Broker. https://github.com/fiware/context.Orion. You should use NGSIv2 APIs, please check http://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development-context-aware-applications/v2/how-to-update-and-query-context-information/ .

You can design a mechanism that will allow to register users, from their mobile phones, and to only allow those registered users to POST data to Orion. As a result your application will be minimally secure. You can for instance design your own simple token based registration mechanism or even you can use the FIWARE IdM, PEP Proxy and Authorization PDP. See my presentation at https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/18LaWZSK4h2wncPF6hNAwK5MToLvJesR3XLrzsqrsmrw/edit?usp=sharing .

The Complex Event Processing can be implemented using FIWARE official CEP, see http://fiwaretourguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/real-time-processing-of-context-events/introduction/ or you can use alternative implementations such as Perseo https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-fe , which uses EsperTech rule system.

I hope this helps